# Issue with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I could swear this was working two days ago, now it throws an exception...

I am checking against some data in a `DataTable`. I'm basically counting how many times a certain `eventID` is found within the last 15 minutes. Here's that code:

```
int startevents = trackingData
    .Select("RHEventID = 3 AND RHDateEvent > #" + now + "#" ).Length;
```

I'm defining the 'now' variable just before that - looks like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
```

However this throws a *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime* exception. Here is an example of the data in the datatable, in the column for RHDateEvent:

> 2017-02-14 13:58:27 PM
>   (edit - yes this is only one date, not two, in the column)

So what am I doing wrong? Do I need to be converting this DateTime somehow?

Comment: Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It may be a problem with using a "#" as delimiter for the date. Did you try single quotes around the date. I am assuming when you put out the test data you were showing two examples of data not one date field holding two dates.

Comment: Yeah single quotes doesn't work, as it doesn't seem to recognise it as a DateTime and effectively ignores that part of the query (I end up with incorrect results if I check it manually). Correct on the data, it's just one date per column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd really recommend to use `Linq-To-DataTable` instead of the old and limited `Select` method:

```
DateTime in15minutes = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
var matchingRows = from row in trackingData.AsEnumerable()
                   where row.Field<int>("RHEventID) == 3
                     &&  row.Field<DateTime>("RHDateEvent") > in15minutes
                   select row;
```

if you now just need the count use:

```
int matchingRowCount = matchingRows.Count();
```

This is more readable, powerful and supports compile time safety.

---

If your column is a not a `DateTime`- but a `string`-column  you need to parse it:

```
...
&&  DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("RHDateEvent"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > in15minutes
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - this looks good, only that it throws an error on the 'in15minutes' variable with exception - 'Specified cast is not valid'. Any ideas?

Comment: @reviloSlater: then it seems that the column `RHDateEvent` is not a `DateTime` column but f.e. a `string`. You need to parse it to `DateTime` then. What format does it have? This: `2017-02-14 13:58:27 PM`?

Comment: yes correct, the format is like you quoted (2017-02-14 13:58:27 PM).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the date time is duplicated...

`2017-02-14 13:58:27 PM 2017-02-14 13:57:27 PM`

instead of

`2017-02-14 13:58:27 PM`

Answer (score 0):

If it's linq to entities use

```
var startevents = trackingData.Where(e => e.RHEventId = 3 && e.RHDateEvent >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15)).Count();
```

Comment: I know *sigh*, how lazy of me!